# Get order of a number in a list contained in a range, unsorted

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I have a range containing numbers, e.g.,

```
+---+-----+
|   |  A  |
+---+-----+
| 1 |  21 |
| 2 |  34 |
| 3 |   0 |
| 4 |  82 |
| 5 | 112 |
| 6 |  92 |
| 7 | 102 |
| 8 |  52 |
| 9 |  67 |
+---+-----+
```

I want a formula to find the order of each of these numbers in the sorted list. E.g, for A3 (=0), it would return 1, and so on.

So far, I could do that with two columns (instead of one):

In B1, use `=SMALL(A$1:A$9,ROW()-ROW(A$1)+1)` (adapted from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/38668-formula-sort-numbers-ascending-value-into-new-column.html), but useful for a list in a row not starting at 1 with suitable referencing).
In C1 use `=MATCH(A1,B$1:B$9,0)`.
Then copy-paste downwards, to obtain the table below.

I am looking for the same, but sparing the intermediate column.

```
+---+-----+-----+---+
|   |  A  |  B  | C |
+---+-----+-----+---+
| 1 |  21 |   0 | 2 |
| 2 |  34 |  21 | 3 |
| 3 |   0 |  34 | 1 |
| 4 |  82 |  52 | 6 |
| 5 | 112 |  67 | 9 |
| 6 |  92 |  82 | 7 |
| 7 | 102 |  92 | 8 |
| 8 |  52 | 102 | 4 |
| 9 |  67 | 112 | 5 |
+---+-----+-----+---+
```

Comment: What results do you wish to see for two or more entries which are identical? Or will the entries in fact always be unique in your set-up?

Comment: @XORLX - Most likely they will always be unique. And if not, see [this complementary answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25118421/2707864)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in B1 and pull down the formula, the 1 at the end signifies ascending order:

```
=RANK(A1,A:A,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`RANK` is the (original) function to use.

In addition, from [Excel 2010 help for RANK](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/rank-function-HP010335659.aspx):
"IMPORTANT  This function has been replaced with one or more new functions that may provide improved accuracy and whose names better reflect their usage. This function is still available for compatibility with earlier versions of Excel. However, if backward compatibility is not required, you should consider using the new functions from now on, because they more accurately describe their functionality.
For more information about the new functions, see [RANK.AVG](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/rank-avg-function-HA010345377.aspx) function and [RANK.EQ](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/rank-eq-function-HP010335687.aspx) function.
"